# How to add proportions to tbl_svysummary() COLUMNS

Tags: r, gtsummary

How to do I add proportions to a tbl summary objects' columns? I'm using `tbl_svysummary()` and the variable fed to the `by=` argument is categorical?

```
 tbl_svysummary(
by = factor_variable, include = c(variables))
```

I would like the column headers (levels of the factor specified in the `by=` argument) to show the proportions of each factor level within the factor variable itself.

I would like the proportions of each level within the column factor variable
[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYtTD.png)

Comment: I tried percent = column and that did not work.

Comment: please update your post with a minimal reproducible example that we can run on our machines aka a reprex. Please also include more details (a mockup of the table?) you're trying to create. I am not sure where you want the proportions to be....

Comment: I added some more clarification

Comment: Use `modify_header()` to add the proportions: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify.html#tbl-summary-tbl-svysummary-and-tbl-cross--1